# Running console app with parameters from NSIS installer

Tags: batch-file, nsis

I am creating one installer for my project. Deployment of project needs some changes that are too complex with NSIS.

So for making it easy I have written one console app in C#. This app will do all the complex changes required with use of some parameters.

I just want to ask what is the way to call this console app with some parameters from my installer?

Is it possible by creating some batch file or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecWait '"$instdir\myapp.exe" /foo "hello world" /bar'` is the basic method.

Use [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt) if you want to hide the console window and [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) or [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in) if you need more control...

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to execute programs from NSIS, as documented here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.2

**Exec** : Execute the specified program and continue immediately

**ExecShell**: Execute the specified program using ShellExecute

**ExecWait**: Execute the specified program and wait for the executed process to quit

the last solution is probably what you need.